# How to enable or disable links in a jsp page through java

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have a web application using servlets, Now i need to add an additional feature that i need to disable or enable the links using a java code(i might create a new class and return the result object  to jsp page).

I saw few examples but most of them says using Javascript but my requirement is with java.

Any suggestions please-:)

Comment: You specifically say Java code, but are you able to use tag libraries in your JSP?

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in a JSP is actually very painless!

```
<%@ page language ="java"%>

<%
boolean b = true;
if(b){
    %>
    <a href="link">first</a>
    <%
else{
    %>
    <a href="other link">other</a>
    <%
}
%>

OTHER HTML HERE
```

JSPs really are pretty magic, you can mix Java and HTML as you need, just keep <% %> tags around the java code.

And remember that JSPs are all generated server-side, so you can't do any real-time client handling logic. It is all executed before the user ever sees the page, and he just receives the static HTML output of the java.